# PHP SimpleXML Group By Element Type

Tags: php, xml, group-by, grouping, simplexml

Ok here's my dilemma. I am looking for a way to consolidate the data in a group using **SimpleXML in PHP**. Here's what I mean.

Let's say I have an xml that looks like this:

```
  <favorites>
    <interesting>
        <type>Movie</type>
        <character>James Bond</character>
        <name>Casino Royale</name>
    </interesting>
    <interesting>
        <type>Movie</type>
        <character>Jason Bourne</character>
        <name>Bourne Identity</name>
    </interesting>
    <interesting>
        <type>Book</type>
        <character>Lindsay Ford</character>
        <name>Shantaram</name>
    </interesting>
  </favorites>
```

Now here's what I want that to look like:

**Movie**

- Casino Royale - James Bond Bourne
- Bourne Identity - Jason Bourne

**Book**

- Shantaram - Lindsay Ford

Please help me!! Let me know if anything is confusing.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I forgot to mention that there is huge list of "types" and I don't want to write xpath for each one, is there a way to automatically find "types" instead of hard coding the values (eg. "Movie", "Book")?

Comment: $arrTypes = $xml->xpath('interesting/type');  will give you all of the types. Unfortunately it will be an array of simplexml objects. You'll need to loop over it and put all of the types into a new array, and then array_unique() the new array.

Comment: Can you help me out on this a little more? I am a n00b. :( Thanks man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know in advance the types of movies, you could :

- extract all types from the XML data

  - get them as unique, as they may appear several times (There might be a way to do that with XPath ; I don't know it, so I'll use `array_unique`)
- iterate over these types, using what [@Mark proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209301/php-simplexml-group-by-element-type/1209519#1209519).

Something like this would probably do :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);

$typesListXml = $xml->xpath('interesting/type');
var_dump($typesListXml);    // var_dump #1

if (!empty($typesListXml)) {
    $typesList = array();
    foreach ($typesListXml as $typeXml) {
        $typesList[] = (string)$typeXml;
    }
    var_dump($typesList);    // var_dump #2

    $typesList = array_unique($typesList);
    var_dump($typesList); // var_dump #3

    $moviesForType = array();
    foreach ($typesList as $type) {
        $rawData = $xml->xpath('interesting[type="' . $type . '"]');
        if (!empty($rawData)) {
            foreach ($rawData as $rawMovie) {
                $moviesForType[$type][] = $rawMovie->name . ' - ' . $rawMovie->character;
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($moviesForType); // var_dump #4

    // Up to you to present $moviesForType the way you want ;-)

}
```

And to make things easier to understand, here are the var_dump's outputs :

**var_dump #1** :

```
array
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      string 'Movie' (length=5)
  1 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
      string 'Movie' (length=5)
  2 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
      string 'Book' (length=4)
```

**var_dump #2** :

```
array
  0 => string 'Movie' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Movie' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Book' (length=4)
```

**var_dump #3** :

```
array
  0 => string 'Movie' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Book' (length=4)
```

**var_dump #3** :

```
array
  'Movie' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Casino Royale - James Bond' (length=26)
      1 => string 'Bourne Identity - Jason Bourne' (length=30)
  'Book' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Shantaram - Lindsay Ford' (length=24)
```

Now, it's up to you to present those data the way you want ; a double-foreach loop constructing `<ul>` and `<li>` tags would probably do **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Xpath:

```
$xmlData = '<favorites>...</favorites>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);
$arrMovies = $xml->xpath('interesting[type="Movie"]');
$arrBooks = $xml->xpath('interesting[type="Book"]');
```

You can then loop over $arrMovies and $arrBooks and print out what you need:

```
foreach($arrMovies as $movie) {
    echo $movie->name;
}
```