# Read XML attributes using PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

I m using a API to display results w.r.t to search query.

The output will be in the form of XML, I need to parse the XML  and display the result in the browser.

The file contains many attributes from which i m not sure how to extract the results.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns3:tourDetailsFullResponse xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/" xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/">

<ns4:MarketLocalisedTourData SellingCompanyCode="CODE1" OperatingProductCode="CODE2" MarketVariationCode="CODE3" Duration="8" Currency="USD" CatalogueCode="CODE4" TropicsBrochureCode="CODE5" BrandCode="CODE6" BookableOnline="true">

<ns4:TourInfo>
<ns4:TourName>London to Rome Highlights 2013</ns4:TourName>
<ns4:Metadata>
    <ns4:TourCategories>
        <ns4:TourCategory Name="TourStyles">
            <ns4:CategoryValue Name="European Discoveries"/>
        </ns4:TourCategory>
    </ns4:TourCategories>
    <ns4:Brochures>
        <ns4:Brochure Name="CostSaver 2013" Code="CODE1"/>
    </ns4:Brochures>
</ns4:Metadata>
<ns4:ContinentsVisited>
    <ns4:Continent Name="Europe" Code="EURO"/>
</ns4:ContinentsVisited>
<ns4:CountriesVisited>
    <ns4:Country Name="France" Continent="EURO" Code="FR"/>
    <ns4:Country Name="United Kingdom" Continent="EURO" Code="GB"/>
    <ns4:Country Name="Italy" Continent="EURO" Code="IT"/>
    <ns4:Country Name="Switzerland" Continent="EURO" Code="CH"/>
</ns4:CountriesVisited>
<ns4:LocationsVisited>
    <ns4:Location Name="Paris" Country="FR"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Dover" Country="GB"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="London" Country="GB"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Rome" Country="IT"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Calais" Country="FR"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Venice" Country="IT"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Lucerne" Country="CH"/>
    <ns4:Location Name="Florence" Country="IT"/>
</ns4:LocationsVisited>
<ns4:Description>A lively journey through elegant Paris, gorgeous Lake Lucerne, charming Venice and cultural Florence, bookended by stays in London and legendary Rome. Spend a day at leisure in London and get the best views of Rome from high up in St. Peterâ€™s Basilica before throwing a lucky coin in Trevi Fountain.</ns4:Description>
<ns4:Assets>
    <ns4:Image Width="297" Url="http://www.example.com/imageurl" Type="map" Name="route_map" Height="297" Caption="route_map"/>
    <ns4:Image Width="600" Url="http://www.example.com/imageurl" Type="map" Name="route_map" Height="600" Caption="route_map"/>
    <ns4:Image Width="531" Url="http://www.example.com/imageurl" Type="photo" Name="primary_image" Height="531" Caption="primary_image"/>
    <ns4:Image Width="125" Url="http://www.example.com/imageurl" Type="photo" Name="primary_image" Height="125" Caption="primary_image"/>
</ns4:Assets>
  ....continues
```

Now i want to extract the continents visited , countries visited, locations visited, itinerary, assests etc...

I tried using simple xml like the following

```
$feed = "response1_full.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

print_r($xml);

foreach($xml->LocationsVisited[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
also tried 
foreach($xml->TourInfo->LocationsVisited[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

also tried all other possibilities which results in same error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\xmlread2.php on line 10

I m searching a solution for this more than couple of days.

Comment: The solution you look for implies that you understand what namespaces in XML are and [how to access namespaced elements with simplexml](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+access+namespaced+elements+with+simplexml). So please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to traverse into children in their own namespace you have to tell SimpleXMLElement which namespace:

```
$ns4 = $xml->children('S', true)->Body
        ->children('ns3', true)->tourDetailsFullResponse
            ->children('ns4', true);

$locations = $ns4->MarketLocalisedTourData->TourInfo->LocationsVisited->Location;

foreach ($locations as $location) {
    $attributes = $location->attributes();
    echo $attributes['Name'];
    echo $attributes['Country'];
}
```

However you can make your life more easy by using [xpath with the namespace(s) you're interested in by registering them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml).

Comment: I tried your suggesstion which results in `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\xmlread2.php on line 10`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include TourInfo

Comment: Actually i tried including that too but no change in the result.

Getting the same error.

Comment: Can you paste (in pastebin for example) the actual XML, I will do a test again (the previous example works in my machine)

Comment: @m4t1t0: You missed to specify the namespaces, I edited your answer.

Answer (score 1):

what does $xml have? can you print the result.
And if it **does not contain the any thing**

then the problem is with namespace
look at he following question:
[Remove namespace from XML using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245902/remove-namespace-from-xml-using-php)

```
$feed = "response1_full.xml";
echo "<pre>";
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($feed);
if ($sxe === false) {
echo "Failed loading XML\n";
foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
    echo "\t", $error->message;
}
}
if (file_exists('response1_full.xml')) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file('response1_full.xml');
 //print_r($xml);
 } else {
exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}
print_r($sxe->Body->tourDetailsFullResponse->MarketLocalisedTourData->TourInfo->LocationsVisited->Location[0]);
print_r($sxe->Body->tourDetailsFullResponse->MarketLocalisedTourData->TourInfo->LocationsVisited->Location[1]);
```

Comment: If i print $xml i get the following answer :

    `SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) `

And i already have the file saved under the name and why should i load the file as string and save the XML once again !? Sorry i dont understand..

Comment: the problem is with your namespace remove the namespace and corresponding namespce from tags and see if your are getting any output

Comment: your problem is with namespace when i removed the namespaces and tried to assess the the object it worked

Answer (score 1):

Finally i managed to find the answer through DOM.

@Deepak Srinivasan : I tried your suggestions to register the namespace before executing but i didnt get over it, may b i m not sure how to proceed.

@m4t1t0: Thank you for your response.

i have pasted the pastebin url of the full file, You all can see the file from the URL specified below the answer.

I got the solution using the getAttribute method

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'response1_full.xml' );

//tourname
$tname = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "TourName" );
$tourname = $tname->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $tourname;
//locations visited
$locations = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "Location" );
foreach( $locations as $location )
{

    $locationname = $location->getAttribute('Name');
    $locationcountry = $location->getAttribute('Country');

    echo $locationname.'-'.$locationcountry.'<br>';
}
```

Which prints out the required details exactly.

But now i have a small doubt in the same file, 
I have some information's in nested format, is there anyway that i can pull it easily.!?

Here is my file for that
http://pastebin.com/iWQf6j4K

Insde the file you can see a section

```
<ns4:WhatsIncluded>
```

which has title and text(ul - li format)

Is there any way i can pull the datas inside this secion.
if i pull data from **Text** under **Section** i get the *li* items totally as a single paragraph,

but when i use foreach inside **Text** i get only the first *li* item,

I also tried foreach for  **Text** *ul*, but still only one result.

Any suggestions..

Many thanks.